# Pandas not accurately matching header to values of csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to create a pivot table to analyze data using pandas. My data is in a csv file (`data.csv`) without a header. I append the following array to the top of the file when reading it in via pandas:

```
Labels = ['voter_id_org','State ID','city','ward','pct','name_last','name_first','name_middle','name_suffix','Status,party','Registration Date','Last Registration Date','house_no','pre_dir','street','apartment','zip','birth_date','voter_id','Source','P_05_02_2017','S_12_06_2016','G_11_08_2016','S_08_02_2016','S_06_21_2016','P_03_15_2016','S_12_08_2015','G_11_03_2015','P_09_08_2015','P_05_05_2015','S_02_03_2015','G_11_04_2014','S_08_05_2014','P_05_06_2014','G_11_05_2013','P_10_01_2013','P_09_10_2013','S_08_06_2013','P_05_07_2013','G_11_06_2012','S_08_07_2012','P_03_06_2012','G_11_08_2011','P_09_13_2011','S_08_02_2011','P_05_03_2011','S_02_08_2011','G_11_02_2010','P_09_07_2010','S_08_03_2010','P_05_04_2010','G_11_03_2009','P_09_29_2009','P_09_08_2009','S_08_04_2009','P_05_05_2009','S_02_03_2009','SG_12_23_2008','SG_11_18_2008','G_11_04_2']
```

However, I'm not able to accurate reference specific columns via their labels and as a result my pivot table is empty. My code creates a pivot table when the csv is strictly comma separated so I think the problem is the `"` between the rows in `data.csv`. How do properly read this file in so that I can access each individual column?

data.csv:

```
547212,OH0014718999,CLEVELAND,03,H,JOHNSON,JAMES,M,,A,NOPTY,01/01/1901,09/19/2016,1500,,DETROIT AVE,     APT 505,44113,1959,547212,VOTER PARTICIPATION CENTER,,,Y,,,,,,,,,,,,Y,,,,,Y,,,Y,,,,,Y,,,,Y,,,,,,,,Y,,,,D,,,,,,,,,,Y,,,,,CLEV CSD,CONG 11,HSE 10,SEN 21,CLE MCD,"CCD 07
"
652898,OH0014779218,CLEVELAND,03,Q,WOLSTEIN,JILLIAN,MARCY,,A,NOPTY,01/01/1901,03/22/2017,1055,,OLD RIVER RD,     APT 811,44113,1960,652898,5 - RECEIVED IN MAIL,,,Y,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,CLEV CSD,CONG 11,HSE 10,SEN 21,CLE MCD,"CCD 07
"
2417233,OH0020357576,CLEVELAND,07,J,PYNE,DANIEL,J,,I,NOPTY,10/06/2008,10/06/2008,1701,E, 12TH ST,         14Q,44114,1984,2417233,SECRETARY OF STATE S OFFICE,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Y,,,,,,,,Y,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,CLEV CSD,CONG 11,HSE 10,SEN 21,CLE MCD,"CCD 07
"
2407693,OH0020299723,CLEVELAND,03,H,ANGELO,CELIA,E,,A,NOPTY,10/06/2008,07/08/2015,1500,,DETROIT AVE,     APT 102,44113,1985,2407693,5 - RECEIVED IN MAIL,,,Y,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Y,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,CLEV CSD,CONG 11,HSE 10,SEN 21,CLE MCD,"CCD 07
    "
...
```

My file:

```
def analyzefile(file):
    f = pd.read_csv(file,header=None,names=labels)
    pt = pd.pivot_table(f,index=['State ID'], aggfunc='count')
    print pt
```

Comment: If you are splitting on commas, you don't have the same number of columns in your header (60) and the first line of the file (85). Also, I can't tell if this is a mistake--a comma in the name of one of the headers ? `'Status,party'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to accurately reference specific columns in the dataframe because the length of `df.columns` is 85 and the length of `Labels` list is 60. In case you want to pivot the dataframe like this you can do like below.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv',delimiter=',',header=None)
pd.pivot_table(df,index=1,aggfunc='count')
```

And the problem is not the `"` between the rows in `data.csv` because they are the closing `"` of the last item in that row

Comment: Good catch, never would have found that. That's a really dumb error.